# Where can I find the Arduino Mega core code?

Tags: arduino-mega, core-libraries

I am looking to modify the receiving hardware serial buffer size for the Arduino Mega. To do so I need to redefine it in `HardwareSerial.h` in the core code. However, I can't seem to find a copy of the Arduino Mega core code. A search for `HardwareSerial.h` on my computer returns no results. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: And how / where on your computer did you search? Did you look inside the Arduino software itself?

Comment: Here https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino Mega is part of the Arduino AVR Boards core. The location of that core depends on whether you are using the core version included with the Arduino IDE or have updated the core version using Boards Manager(in which case there will be multiple copies of the core installed on your computer but only the updated version will be used). The easiest way to find it is:

1. Tools > Board > Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560
2. File > Examples > EEPROM > eeprom_clear
3. Sketch > Show Sketch Folder
4. Move up folder levels until you reach the `avr` folder.
5. If there is a version number folder in the `avr` folder then open that folder.
6. HardwareSerial.h and the rest of the core files are located in `cores/arduino`.

Remember that you will need to redo any changes to the core after any Arduino IDE and/or Arduino AVR Boards updates.